# Android studio: How to delete crashlytics plugin

Tags: android, android-studio, crashlytics

I'm using Android Studio 1.0.2.

Due to some reason i have to uninstall the Crashlytics plugin/SDK from my Android studio.

I have tried going to File>Settings>Plugins to remove Crashlytics, but this has not helped me, as i cannot find it in the plugin list.

Request if someone can provide a solution for this issue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to delete crashlytics in `app/build.gradle`.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'http://download.crashlytics.com/maven' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.crashlytics.tools.gradle:crashlytics-gradle:1.+'
    }
}
```

```
compile 'com.crashlytics.android:crashlytics:1.+'
```

Delete line that show crashlytics in repositories and dependencies.
Delete file `app/crashlytics.properties` and `app/main/assets/crashlytics-build.properties`
Then build gradle again.

Answer (score 5):

For plugins installed inside the Studio just go to File-Settings-Plugins and uninstall
[image]

Answer (score 5):

You can go to the *Preferences->Plugins* on the search bar, you can search the plugin you want to remove or you can go >installed plugin tab and it will show you the list of installed plugin then select the plugin to remove just right click on it and it will show you the option>uninstall and then press on the Uninstall button.

*File > Setting > plugins > installed plugins > right click on plugin > uninstall*

Answer (score 4):

In case you cannot delete a Plugin from Preferences->Plugins because is not on the list, navigate to

`{User-Home}\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Toolbox\apps\AndroidStudio\ch-0\202.6787931.plugins`

and simply delete its folder and restart Android Studio.

You may have to look up that path yourself, as mine is for a JetBrains Toolbox installation of Android Studio, but the process should be the same.

Hint: In my case the plugin in question lived in a folder named "plugin", what I had to figure out first.

Answer (score 1):

For Mac User find plugin on below path.

> /Users/**username**/Library/Application
> Support/Google/AndroidStudio**2021.3**/Plugins

Bold text would be different depending on computer environment + Android Studio version

Answer (score 1):

For the new Android Studio version (Android Studio Electric Eel | 2022.1.1).
To delete or uninstall the Plugin, the steps are below:

**Settings** -> **Plugins** -> Choose Tab **Installed** -> **Select the Plugin** you want -> Click **Icon Setting** (Right of Title) -> **Uninstall**

Comment: Thanks! I appreciated the simplicity here.